# Not aggregating correctly

Tags: r, aggregate

My goal of this code is to create a loop that aggregates each company's word frequency by a certain principle vector I created and adds it to a list. The problem is, after I run this, it only prints the 7 principles that I have rather than the word frequencies along side them. The word frequencies being the certain column of the FREQBYPRINC.AG data frame. Individually, running this code without the loop and just testing out a certain column, it works no problem. For some reason, the loop doesn't want to give me the correct data frames for the list. Any suggestions?

```
list.agg<-vector("list",ncol(FREQBYPRINC.AG)-2)
for (i in 1:14){
attach(FREQBYPRINC.AG)
list.agg[i]<-aggregate(FREQBYPRINC.AG[,i+1],by=list(Type=principle),FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you have the `attach()` in the `for` loop, it only needs to be done once. Also the `[,i+1]` looks a bit odd.

Comment: Whenever I see a `for` in r I know something is wrong.

Comment: Please provide some example data

Answer (score 0):

I really wish I could help. After reading your statement, It seems that to you , you feel that the code should be working and it is not. Well maybe there exists a glitch.

Since you had previously specified list. agg as a list, you need to subset it with double square brackets. Try this one out:

```
    list.agg<-vector("list",ncol(FREQBYPRINC.AG)-2)
    for (i in 1:14){
    list.agg[[i]]<-aggregate(FREQBYPRINC.AG[,i+1],by=list 
                                (Type=principle),FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE)}
```